# python convert pdf files to eps

Tags: python, pdf, eps

hello I have many pdf files and I eant to convert to .eps using python.

I have find some codes but don't work for me that codes execute without some error but I don't take some .eps file .

any idea ?

I have python 2.7.13

code 1 :

```
from glob import *
from os import system
fileList = glob('*.pdf')
for f in fileList:
  system('pdftops -eps {0}'.format(f))
```

code 2 :

```
import os, re, sys 
dirList = os.listdir( '.' )
try:
    os.mkdir( 'EpsFigs' )
except:
    pass
for f in dirList:
    m = re.match('([\w\-]+).(|jpg|jp2|png|pdf|)$',f)
    if m:
        cmd = 'convert %s EpsFigs/%s.eps'%( f, m.group(1) )
        os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: why not convert via command line directly?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest how ?

Answer (score 2):

Use linux command `pdf2ps` to convert pdf to eps.

> ```
> pdf2ps [ options ] input.pdf [output.ps]
> ```

For example,

```
pdf2ps input.pdf output.eps
```

If you really want to use python, you can call the above command with `subprocess.call`:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["pdf2ps", "input.pdf", "output.eps"])
```

#### Reference

- [`pdf2ps`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/pdf2ps.htm)
- [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: i have error with this code `WindowsError: [Error 2] ` any idea why ?